# Let htaccess to point static resources to a subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have put my (Wordpress) site `wpsite.com` in a folder `mysite` (instead of root). Here's the .htaccess file (on root) to forward all the `mysite` related requests to the folder `mysite`.

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

### all the missite.com rules here (just simple rules) ###

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Problem is, there's another site (`missite.com`) at root. So according to the rules above, requests like: `mysite.com/a-wp-page/` work good. But not:

- `mysite.com` - It just loads the index.php of the site at root.
- `mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twenty11/style.css` - Static resources, nothing to do with index.php. So these won't be redirected unless ruled separately.

How can I solve both above issues?

Comment: If you have `missite.com` site at root, why are you rewriting all requests to `/mysite/`?

Comment: Edited the question...